# Dynamic Disable using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to disable a set of Radios on a button click event which are dynamically generated using ng-repeat, however I need to only disable radiobuttons which are not checked.

```
<label class="radio" ng-repeat="questionValue in question.values">
    <input type="radio" name="{{question.name}}"
           ng-model="attrs[question.name]" value="{{questionValue[1]}}" >
    <i></i>
    {{questionValue[0]}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following :

```
<label class="radio" ng-repeat="questionValue in question.values">
    <input type="radio" name="{{question.name}}"
           ng-model="attrs[question.name]" value="{{questionValue[1]}}" 
           ng-disabled="disabler[$index]">
    <i></i>
    {{questionValue[0]}}
</label>
```

Then inside the controller, you can create an array of booleans :

```
$scope.disabler = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.question.values.length; i++){
    $scope.disabler.push(false);
}
```

Then inside your click handler, you add your logic :

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.disabler.length; i++){
    if (yourLogic)
       $scope.disabler[i] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-disabled attribute. Then set a value on your controller when your button is clicked and then something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{question.name}}"
           ng-model="attrs[question.name]" value="{{questionValue[1]}}"
ng-disabled="[yourButtonValue] && [radioButton.disabled] == false" >
```